# Solve $(y'')^2 + 2y(y') + y^2 = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve this differential equation?

$$(y'')^2 + 2y(y') + y^2 = 0$$

I am assuming this is easy to solve. However I haven't worked on differential equations for quite some time and I'm forgetting most of it. Any hint/reference would be appreciated.

Comment: One can find *some* solutions easily, for example $Ae^{-x}$. There is another of type $Ae^{-kx}$ for a real $k$, and a couple of complex $k$, which can maybe be turned into sines and cosines.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How did you find these? Just by inspection?

Comment: Sort of, at least without writing down anything. Because of the shape, it is natural to look for solutions of the form $e^{-kx}$, which gives $k^4-2k+1=0$, with the obvious root $1$ and therefore another real root.

Comment: $u=\dfrac{y^\prime}{y}$ will reduce the order and give a term $u^4+2u+1$ looking suspiciously close to @AndréNicolas $k^4-2k+1$ but I do not know where to go from there.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales: It is the same, the minus sign was because I like my constants to be positive.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha seems to be able to solve the reduced DE: $(u' + u^2)^2 + 2u +1=0$. Here it is. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(dp%2Fdt+%2Bp%5E2)%5E2%2B2p%2B1%3D0

Comment: What is the independent variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$(y'')^2+2y(y')+y^2=0$

$\left(\dfrac{y''}{y}\right)^2+\dfrac{2y'}{y}+1=0$

This belongs to an ODE of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0511.pdf.

Let $u=\dfrac{y'}{y}$ ,

Then $u'=\dfrac{y''}{y}-\dfrac{(y')^2}{y^2}=\dfrac{y''}{y}-u^2$

$\therefore(u'+u^2)^2+2u+1=0$

$(u'+u^2)^2=-2u-1$

$u'+u^2=\pm i\sqrt{2u+1}$

$u'=-u^2\pm i\sqrt{2u+1}$